# Failed to run livox-SDK2 on Jetson Orin Nano(ARM)

Tags: sdk, lidar

I have a **MID-360 lidar**, and i want to run it on my **Jetson Orin Nano**, so I tried to install the **Livox-SDK2** on my jetson orin nano. My system is **Ubuntu20.04**, my ROS is **ROS1 noetic**

I believe i have done everything following the README on https://github.com/Livox-SDK/Livox-SDK2, there was no error when compiling. However, when i connect the lidar and run the sample programe: livox_lidar_quick_start, i just can't get the pointcloud data. It just stack there without any output like following:
[I just stack at here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IireL.jpg)

Considering my Jetson Orin Nano is based on ARM, I am suspecting that is the ARM structure that caused the Livox-SDK2 failed to run. Does any body succeeded running Livox-SDK2 on Jetson Orin Nano or other ARM platform? I really appreciate your help!

Here is my ip and the config files when connecting the lidar:

[config.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp4az.jpg)

[mid360_config.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N7Re.jpg)

[my ip settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rejb3.jpg)

and i expected to receive the pointcloud data like flowing:

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e14Nx.png)